# Get parameter value in template

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-templates, django-urls

I have such url pattern:

```
url(r'^drinks/(?P<drink_name>\D+)/',TemplateView.as_view(template_name='drinks/index.
html'),name="drink")
```

How can I get access to drink_name parameter value in template.

Comment: Did you try just `drink_name`?

Answer (score 0):

You can access the variable of the URL in the template as follows:

```
{{view.drink_name}}
```

regards

Comment: `view.kwargs.drink_name` should be the way if the view is available in the context.

Comment: yes, "view.kwargs.drink_name" works, thanks a lot, I will go on reading to get know what context is.

Comment: Yes, that work in the view and template, but, in class based views, by default, the context variable 'view' is passed with the values of kwargs, then you can access to those attributes in your template file simply by: {{view.attribute}}.